# java.lang.NullPointerException en arreglo

Tags: java, array

He pasado las ultimas dos horas intentando ver en donde me estoy equivocando, pero no lo encuentro. Tengo que hacer una actividad para la escuela de un estado de cuenta, que lee el saldo inicial y cantidad de movimientos, el tipo y monto de los movimientos, y calcula el saldo final, con unas penalizaciones si aplican.

El error que me sale es el siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Actividad1$Movimiento.access$202(Actividad1.java:204)
    at Actividad1$Cuenta.setMovimiento(Actividad1.java:159)
    at Actividad1.main(Actividad1.java:124)
```

Y el codigo en estas lineas:

```
124: CuentaCliente.setMovimiento(i, tipo, monto);
159: this.movimientos_mes[posicion].tipo = tipo;
204: private static class Movimiento{
```

El codigo completo es el siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;

public class Actividad1 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Crear variables
    Cuenta CuentaCliente = new Cuenta();
    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
    boolean Error = true;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double k;
    int x;
    int tipo = 0;
    double monto = 0;


    System.out.println("Ingresa Saldo Inicial: ");

    while(Error) {
        //Verifica que la entrada sea el formato correcto
              if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                k = sc.nextDouble();
                k = abs(k);
                CuentaCliente.setSaldoInicial(k);
              }
              else {
                System.out.println("Formato de ingreso invalido,ingresa un numero positivo");
                System.out.println("Ingresa Saldo Inicial: ");
                sc.next();
                continue; 
              }
              Error = false;
            }

    System.out.println("Ingresa Cantidad de Movimientos: ");

    Error = true;
    while(Error) {
              if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                x = sc.nextInt();
                x = abs(x);
                CuentaCliente.setCantidadMovimientos(x);
              }
              else {
                System.out.println("Formato de ingreso invalido, ingresa un numero integro");
                System.out.println("Ingresa Cantidad de Movimientos: ");
                sc.next();
                continue; 
              }
              Error = false;
            }   

   //Crear arreglo para los movimientos del mes
   CuentaCliente.movimientos_mes = new Movimiento[CuentaCliente.getCantidadMovimientos()];
   int n = CuentaCliente.movimientos_mes.length;
   System.out.println(n);
   x = 0;
   double y = 0;             

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){

        System.out.println("Ingresa Tipo de Movimiento para Movimiento " + (i+1) +":");
        System.out.println("Deposito: 1");
        System.out.println("Retiro: 2");

        Error = true;
        while(Error) {
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
              x = sc.nextInt();

                if ((x == 1) || (x == 2)){
                    tipo = x;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Ingresa uno de los siguientes opciones: (1/2)");
                    System.out.println("Deposito: 1");
                    System.out.println("Retiro: 2");
                    sc.next();
                    continue; 
                }

            }
            else {
              System.out.println("Formato de ingreso invalido, ingresa un numero integro");
              System.out.println("Ingresa Tipo de Movimiento para Movimiento " + (i+1) +":");
              System.out.println("Deposito: 1");
              System.out.println("Retiro: 2");
              sc.next();
              continue; 
            }
            Error = false;
        } 


        System.out.println("Ingresa Monto de Movimiento para Movimiento " + (i+1) +":");

        Error = true;
        while(Error) {
              if (sc.hasNextDouble())
                monto = sc.nextDouble();
              else {
                System.out.println("Ingreso invalido");
                System.out.println("Ingresa Monto de Movimiento para Movimiento" + i +":");
                sc.next();
                continue; 
              }
              Error = false;
            }

        CuentaCliente.setMovimiento(i, tipo, monto);             
   }  

   double saldoNuevo;
    saldoNuevo = CuentaCliente.calculaSaldo(CuentaCliente.saldo_inicial, CuentaCliente.movimientos_mes);

   System.out.println(df2.format(saldoNuevo));
}

private static class Cuenta {
    //Declarar variables
    private double saldo_inicial; 
    private int cantidad_movimientos;
    private Movimiento[] movimientos_mes;

    //Constructor sin argumentos
    Cuenta () {
        saldo_inicial = 0.0;
        cantidad_movimientos = 0;
    }

    Cuenta (double saldo_inicial, int cantidad_movimientos) {
        this.saldo_inicial = saldo_inicial;
        this.cantidad_movimientos = cantidad_movimientos;
   }

   public void setSaldoInicial(double saldo_inicial){
       this.saldo_inicial = saldo_inicial; 
   }

   public void setCantidadMovimientos(int cantidad_movimientos){
       this.cantidad_movimientos = cantidad_movimientos; 
   }

   public void setMovimiento(int posicion, int tipo, double monto){
       this.movimientos_mes[posicion].tipo = tipo;
       this.movimientos_mes[posicion].monto = monto;
   }

   public Movimiento getMovimiento(int posicion){
       return movimientos_mes[posicion];
   }

    public double getSaldoInicial(){
        return saldo_inicial;
    }

    public int getCantidadMovimientos(){
        return cantidad_movimientos;
    }

    public double calculaSaldo(double saldo_inicial, Movimiento[] transaccion){
        double saldo_nuevo = 0;
        int n = transaccion.length;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
            if (transaccion[i].tipo == 1){
                if (transaccion[i].monto < 5000)
                    saldo_nuevo = saldo_inicial + transaccion[i].monto - 50;

                else 
                    saldo_nuevo = saldo_inicial + transaccion[i].monto;
            }

            if (transaccion[i].tipo == 2){
                if (transaccion[i].monto < 5000)
                    saldo_nuevo = saldo_inicial - transaccion[i].monto - 50;

                else 
                    saldo_nuevo = saldo_inicial - transaccion[i].monto;
            }
        }

        if (n > 10)
            saldo_nuevo = saldo_nuevo - ((n - 10)*5);

        return saldo_nuevo;
    }    
}    

private static class Movimiento{

       private int tipo;
       private double monto;


       public void setTipo(int tipo){
           this.tipo = tipo; 
       }

       public void setMonto(double monto){
           this.monto = monto; 
       }

       public int getTipo(){
           return tipo; 
       }

       public double getMonto(){
           return monto; 
       }


    }  
}
```

¿Alguien me puede dar un idea en donde me estoy equivocando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema es que el arreglo `movimientos_mes` tiene elementos vacíos. Si bien lo creas en la siguiente línea:

```
CuentaCliente.movimientos_mes = new Movimiento[CuentaCliente.getCantidadMovimientos()];
```

Nunca le agregas elementos al arreglo, por lo que al ejecutarse este código:

```
public void setMovimiento(int posicion, int tipo, double monto) {
    this.movimientos_mes[posicion].tipo = tipo;
    this.movimientos_mes[posicion].monto = monto;
}
```

Aparece la excepción `NullPointerException`.

Para resolver esto, podrías realizar lo siguiente:

```
public void setMovimiento(int posicion, int tipo, double monto) {
    if (movimientos_mes[posicion] == null) {
        movimientos_mes[posicion] = new Movimiento();
    }
    /* resto del código */
}
```

Comment: Yo pense que estaba agregando elementos al arreglo con el metodo set Movimiento en el ciclo for.  (CuentaCliente.setMovimiento(i, tipo, monto);)

Comment: O sea para cada version del ciclo pensé que se estaba agregando elementos al arreglo. CuentaCliente.movimientos_mes. Como adaptaría el código para implementar esto? Cambiaría linea 124? O los constructores de la clase?

Comment: Al realizar el debug respectivo, puedes ver que `this.movimientos_mes[posicion]` tiene como valor `null`. Por ende, al acceder a cualquier atributo o método de una variable `null` se lanza el `NullPointerException,`

Comment: Respuesta actualizada con una posible solución. No he leido en detenimiento todo tu código, por lo que es posible que existan otras formas de solucionar tu problema. Lo único que debes asegurarte es de que la variable que quieres utilizar no tenga valor `null`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Ya me salio al agregar lo que me puso

Answer (score 2):

Este tipo de error se presenta cuando una variable que referencia a un objeto se encuentra sin objeto, es decir que puede no haber sido inicializada asignándole un objeto mediante la instrucción new.

Comment: En Java, puedes crear objetos sin llamar al constructor `new` y sin utilizar reflección.